# In Grid Layout the Jbutton size is not changing with the use of setBounds() in java

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, grid-layout

While making a frame using GridLayout the button size is not changing using setBound(). The code for the frame is :

```
f1=new JFrame("Select any one");
            ch=new JCheckBox("SUBSTITUTION CYPHER");
            ch1=new JCheckBox("two");
            ch2=new JCheckBox("three");
            ch3=new JCheckBox("four");
            ch4=new JCheckBox("five");

            f1.add(ch);
            f1.add(ch1);
            f1.add(ch2);
            f1.add(ch3);
            f1.add(ch4);
            f1.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
            b10.addActionListener(this);
            b10.setBounds(280,380,10,10);
            f1.add(b10);
            f1.setSize(300,400);
            f1.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Do you realize that if that button were where the code sets the bounds to, it would be outside the visible area of the frame set by `setSize(..)`?  Further at 10 pixels width X height, it is very small!  Oh, and `"Select any one"` suggests 1) this should (probably) be a modal dialog or option pane. 2) The check boxes should (possibly) be radio buttons which are (definitely) in a button group (which enforces at most one choice per group).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GridLayout isn't the best choice for buttons as GridLayout will take up all space in its container. So no setBounds() won't be the best choice for what you're trying to achieve.

I would suggest having a look at this reference for LayoutManagers: [Reference for LayoutManagers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

I would suggest looking at some alternative LayoutManagers. You could try GridBagLayout.

Answer (score 2):

According to [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)) of `setBounds`

> This method changes layout-related information, and therefore,
>   invalidates the component hierarchy.

So, `setBounds` sets the size and position with layout specific. At your `JFrame` you set `GridLayout`, where `setBounds` will not work.

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to use `GridLayout` you could also first add a `JPanel` to each grid and then add the smaller `JButton` to the `JPanel`.